# Responsive website fails with select tags

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a real estate website and this is the first page. It is supposed to be responsive ( same view on multiple size screens )

But

Start by clicking 'Vanzari Apartamente' (first button from the middle nav).

There is something with my select tags with 'De la' and 'Pana la'

On resize, they go down.

The thing is that they shouldn't and should just stay the same during resizing.

I tried to manage all margins but nothing seems to work.

```js
function closeAllContent() {
    var i, tabcontent;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style = "";
        console.table([tabcontent[i].style.display, tabcontent[i].style.transition, tabcontent[i].style.opacity]);
    }
}

function openContent(event, cityName) {
    document.getElementById(cityName).style.transition = 'opacity 0.5s ease-in-out';
    document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById(cityName).style.opacity = 1;
    event.currentTarget.className += " active";
    console.table([document.getElementById(cityName).style.display, document.getElementById(cityName).style.transition, document.getElementById(cityName).style.opacity]);
}
```

```css
   * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*::selection {
  background-color: yellow;
}

body, html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0.9vh 0.2vw;
  height: 10000px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

body {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

main {
  background-color: rgba(123, 203, 123);
}

br {
  user-select: none;
}

select {
  outline: none;
  margin: 1.2vh 0.3vw;
  border-radius: 0.6vw;
  padding: 0 1.2vw;
  font-size: 0.85vw !important;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border: none;
}
::placeholder {
  appearance: none;
  font-size: 1.5vw !important;
}
#header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 9000px;
  background-image: url("../Images/PozaFundal.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 98vh;
  border-bottom: solid 0.1vw rgb(0, 209, 156);
  margin: auto;
  padding-top: 1vh;
}

#navul {
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: rgb(0, 170, 130);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  border-bottom: solid 0.1vw rgb(0, 209, 156);
}

#navul>li {
  float: left;
}

#navul>li>a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1.3vh 3.3vw;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Forte';
  font-size: 1.4vw;
  border-right: solid 0.1vw rgb(0, 209, 156);
}

.navfirst {
  border-left: solid 0.1vw rgb(0, 209, 156);
}

.navlast {
  float: right !important;
  border-left: solid 0.1vw rgb(0, 209, 156);
}

#navul>li>a:hover {
  background-color: rgb(50, 50, 50)
}

#navul>li.active {
  background-color: rgb(90, 90, 90);
}

img {
  z-index: 0;
}

.title {
  text-align: center;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: white;
  opacity: 0.6;
  text-shadow: -1vw 0 white, 0 1vw white, 1vw 0 white, 0 -1vw white;
  font-size: 3vw;
  color: rgb(104, 71, 37);
  font-weight: 900;
  padding: 1vw;
  font-family: Arial;
}

.tab {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: center;
}

.tablinks {
  background-color: rgb(204, 204, 204);
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 1vh;
  margin: 1.34vh 1.5vw;
  /* transition: 0.2s; */
  font-size: 1.1vw;
  border-radius: 0.5vw;
  width: 10%;
  /* 100 / nr tablinks */
  height: 2%;
}

.tablinks:hover {
  background-color: rgb(177, 177, 177);
}

/*.tablinks.active:not(.adaugaAnunt) {
  background-color: rgb(135, 135, 135);
  border-radius: 8px;
}
*/

.tabcontent {
  opacity: 0;
  margin: 1vw 0;
  padding: 0.4vw 0.8vw;
  background-color: rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.5);
  width: 100%;
  height: 63vh;
  border-radius: 0.8vw;
}

.tabcontent_select_table {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 3vh;
  align-items: center;
}

.tabcontent_select_tablecell_row {
  text-align: center;
}

.rows2 {
  width: 50%; /* peste 50% = una sub alta */
}

.rows4 {
  width: 25%;
}

.tabcontent_title {
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 0.05vw dotted rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  margin-bottom: 3vh;
}

.tabcontent_title>p, p.tabcontent_select_tablecell_row {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 1.5vw;
  color: rgb(245, 255, 250);
  text-shadow: -0.05vw 0 black, 0 0.05vw black, 0.05vw 0 black, 0 -0.05vw black;
}

.topright {
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1.5vw;
  color: red;
  font-weight: 900;
  border: 0.1vw solid red;
  padding: 0 0.4vw;
  border-radius: 0.2vw;
}

.tabcontent_select_table > p {
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.5vw;
  text-shadow: -0.05vw 0 black, 0 0.05vw black, 0.05vw 0 black, 0 -0.05vw black;
}

/* 
div p {
  font-family: 'Gabriola';
  font-size: 22px;
  color: rgb(0,0,92)
} */

/*
.search {
  background-image: url('../Images/search.jpg');
  position: relative;
  background-size:15px 15px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 5px 2px;
}
*/

.search_button {
  width: 18%;
  padding: 0.7vw;
  background: rgb(33, 150, 243);
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.1vw;
  border: 0.05vw solid grey;
  margin: 8vh 42% 0 42%;
}
.errorbox {
  color: red;
  font-size: 1.5vw;
}
.tablinks.adaugaAnunt:not(.active) {
  animation: blinkingText 1s infinite;
}

.tablinks.active.adaugaAnunt {
  animation: noBlinkingText 1s infinite !important;
  background-color: rgb(226, 88, 34);
}

.tablinks.adaugaAnunt>a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

@keyframes blinkingText {
  0% {
    background-color: inherit
  }
  50% {
    background-color: rgb(226, 88, 34)
  }
  100% {
    background-color: inherit
  }
}

@keyframes noBlinkingText {
  0% {
    background-color: rgb(226, 88, 34)
  }
  50% {
    background-color: rgb(226, 88, 34)
  }
  100% {
    background-color: rgb(226, 88, 34)
  }
}

/* 
.custom-select {
  position: relative;
  font-family: Arial;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 227px;
}
.custom-select select {
  display: none;
  hide original SELECT element:
}

.select-selected {
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
}

style the arrow inside the select element:
.select-selected:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: 14px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 6px solid transparent;
  border-color: #fff transparent transparent transparent;
}

point the arrow upwards when the select box is open (active):
.select-selected.select-arrow-active:after {
  border-color: transparent transparent #fff transparent;
  top: 7px;
}

style the items (options), including the selected item:
.select-items div,
.select-selected {
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  border-color: transparent transparent rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
}

style items (options):
.select-items {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgb(50, 50, 130);
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 99;
  width: 225px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.select-items div {
  border-left: 1px solid orangered;
  border-right: 1px solid orangered;
  border-bottom: 1px solid orangered;
  width: 225px;
}

hide the items when the select box is closed:
.select-hide {
  display: none;
}

.select-items div:hover,
.same-as-selected {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
} */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head lang="en">
    <!--|***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************|-->
    <title>Nume Companie Imobiliare</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <!--|***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************|-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/style.css" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="#" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <!--|***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************|-->
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="main">
      <!--|***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************|-->
      <ul id="navul">
        <li class="navfirst"><a class="navli, active" href="../Site-ul de la zero/index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a class="navli" href="../Site-ul de la zero/indexnews.html">News</a></li>
        <li><a class="navli" href="https://www.google.ro" target="blank">Google</a></li>
        <li><a class="navli" href="https://www.facebook.com/trendytravelromania/?ref=br_rs" target="blank">Facebook</a></li>
        <li><a class="navli" href="../Site-ul de la zero/indexcontact.html">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a class="navli" href="../Site-ul de la zero/indexabout.html">About</a></li>
        <li class="navlast"><a class="navli" href="../Site-ul de la zero/indexabout.html">Autentificare</a></li>
      </ul>
      <!--|***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************|-->
      <div id="header">
        <div class="title">Imobiliare Particulari .ro</div>
        <div class="tab">
          <button class="tablinks" onclick="closeAllContent(); openContent(event, 'VanzariApartamente')">Vânzări<br />Apartamente</button>
          <button class="tablinks" onclick="closeAllContent(); openContent(event, 'InchirieriApartamente')">Închirieri<br />Apartamente</button>
          <button class="tablinks" onclick="closeAllContent(); openContent(event, 'VanzariVile')">Vânzări<br />Vile</button>
          <button class="tablinks" onclick="closeAllContent(); openContent(event, 'InchirieriVile')">Închirieri<br />Vile</button>
          <button class="tablinks" onclick="closeAllContent(); openContent(event, 'VanzariTerenuri')">Vânzări<br />Terenuri</button>
          <button class="tablinks" onclick="closeAllContent(); openContent(event, 'InchirieriSpatiiComerciale')">Închirieri<br />Spații&nbsp;Comerciale</button>
          <button class="tablinks adaugaAnunt"><a href="#">Adaugă Anunț<br />GRATUIT</a></button>
        </div>
        <div id="VanzariApartamente" class="tabcontent">
          <span onclick="closeAllContent();" class="topright">×</span>
          <div class="tabcontent_title">
            <p>Vanzări Apartamente</p>
          </div>
          <form class="search_form" action="index_action_search_page.html" method="GET" target="_blank">
            <div class="tabcontent_select_table">
              <p class="tabcontent_select_tablecell_row rows4">Localitatea</p>
              <select name="localitate" class="tabcontent_select_tablecell_row rows4">
                <option value="0">Alege localitatea:</option>
                <option value="1">București</option>
              </select>
              <p class="tabcontent_select_tablecell_row rows4">Numărul de camere</p>
                <select name="nrcamere" class="tabcontent_select_tablecell_row rows4">
                  <option value="0">Alege numărul de camere:</option>
                  <option value="1">1</option>
                  <option value="2">2</option>
                  <option value="3">3</option>
                  <option value="4">4+</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="tabcontent_select_table">
              <p class="tabcontent_select_tablecell_row rows4">Prețul</p>
              <div class="tabcontent_select_tablecell_row rows4">
                  <select name="pretminim" class="tabcontent_select_tablecell_row rows2">
                    <option>De la:</option>
                    <option value="30000">Indiferent</option>
                    <option value="30000">30 mii €</option>
                    <option value="40000">40 mii €</option>
                    <option value="50000">50 mii €</option>
                    <option value="60000">60 mii €</option>
                    <option value="70000">70 mii €</option>
                    <option value="80000">80 mii €</option>
                    <option value="90000">90 mii €</option>
                    <option value="100000">100 mii €</option>
                    <option value="110000">110 mii €</option>
                    <option value="120000">120 mii €</option>
                    <option value="130000">130 mii €</option>
                    <option value="140000">140 mii €</option>
                    <option value="150000">150 mii €</option>
                  </select>
                  <select name="pretmaxim" class="tabcontent_select_tablecell_row rows2">
                    <option>Până la:</option>
                    <option value="150000">Indiferent</option>
                    <option value="10000">10 mii €</option>
                    <option value="20000">20 mii €</option>
                    <option value="30000">30 mii €</option>
                    <option value="40000">40 mii €</option>
                    <option value="50000">50 mii €</option>
                    <option value="60000">60 mii €</option>
                    <option value="70000">70 mii €</option>
                    <option value="80000">80 mii €</option>
                    <option value="90000">90 mii €</option>
                    <option value="100000">100 mii €</option>
                    <option value="110000">110 mii €</option>
                    <option value="120000">120 mii €</option>
                    <option value="130000">130 mii €</option>
                    <option value="140000">140 mii €</option>
                    <option value="150000">150 mii €</option>
                  </select>
              </div>
              <p class="tabcontent_select_tablecell_row rows4">Numărul de m<sup>2</sup></p>
              <div class="tabcontent_select_tablecell_row rows4">
                <select name="nrmpminim" class="tabcontent_select_tablecell_row rows2">
                  <option value="0">De la:</option>
                  <option value="1">y</option>
                  <option value="1">y</option>
                </select>
                <select name="nrmpmaxim" class="tabcontent_select_tablecell_row rows2">
                  <option value="0">Până la:</option>
                  <option value="1">y</option>
                  <option value="1">y</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
            <button class="search_button" type="submit">Caută</button>
          </form>
          <div class="errorbox">Errors</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- <div id="Garsoniere" class="tabcontent">
          <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="topright">&times</span>
          <div>
            <h3>Cauta garsoniere:</h3>
          </div>
          <select class="select">
              <option value="0">Specifica locatia:</option>
              <option value="1">Bucuresti</option>
              <option value="2">Alba Iulia</option>
              <option value="3">Alexandria</option>
              <option value="4">Arad</option>
              <option value="5">Bacau</option>
              <option value="6">Baia Mare</option>
              <option value="7">Bistrita</option>
              <option value="8">Botosani</option>
              <option value="9">Braila</option>
              <option value="10">Brasov</option>
              <option value="11">Buzau</option>
              <option value="12">Calarasi</option>
              <option value="13">Cluj-Napoca</option>
              <option value="14">Craiova</option>
              <option value="15">Deva</option>
              <option value="16">Drobeta Turnu-Severin</option>
              <option value="17">Focsani</option>
              <option value="18">Galati</option>
              <option value="19">Giurgiu</option>
              <option value="20">Iasi</option>
              <option value="21">Miercurea Ciuc</option>
              <option value="22">Oradea</option>
              <option value="23">Piatra Neamt</option>
              <option value="24">Pitesti</option>
              <option value="25">Ploiesti</option>
              <option value="26">Ramnicu Valcea</option>
              <option value="27">Resita</option>
              <option value="28">Satu Mare</option>
              <option value="29">Sf. Gheorghe</option>
              <option value="30">Sibiu</option>
              <option value="31">Slatina</option>
              <option value="32">Slobozia</option>
              <option value="33">Suceava</option>
              <option value="34">Targoviste</option>
              <option value="35">Targu Jiu</option>
              <option value="36">Targu Mures</option>
              <option value="37">Focsani</option>
              <option value="38">Timisoara</option>
              <option value="39">Tulcea</option>
              <option value="40">Vaslui</option>
              <option value="41">Zalau</option>
          </select>
          <select class="select">
            <option value="0">Specifica num:</option>
            <option value="1">Bucuresti</option>
            <option value="2">Alba Iulia</option>
            <option value="3">Alexandria</option>
            <option value="4">Arad</option>
            <option value="5">Bacau</option>
            <option value="6">Baia Mare</option>
            <option value="7">Bistrita</option>
            <option value="8">Botosani</option>
            <option value="9">Braila</option>
            <option value="10">Brasov</option>
            <option value="11">Buzau</option>
            <option value="12">Calarasi</option>
            <option value="13">Cluj-Napoca</option>
            <option value="14">Craiova</option>
            <option value="15">Deva</option>
            <option value="16">Drobeta Turnu-Severin</option>
            <option value="17">Focsani</option>
            <option value="18">Galati</option>
            <option value="19">Giurgiu</option>
            <option value="20">Iasi</option>
            <option value="21">Miercurea Ciuc</option>
            <option value="22">Oradea</option>
            <option value="23">Piatra Neamt</option>
            <option value="24">Pitesti</option>
            <option value="25">Ploiesti</option>
            <option value="26">Ramnicu Valcea</option>
            <option value="27">Resita</option>
            <option value="28">Satu Mare</option>
            <option value="29">Sf. Gheorghe</option>
            <option value="30">Sibiu</option>
            <option value="31">Slatina</option>
            <option value="32">Slobozia</option>
            <option value="33">Suceava</option>
            <option value="34">Targoviste</option>
            <option value="35">Targu Jiu</option>
            <option value="36">Targu Mures</option>
            <option value="37">Focsani</option>
            <option value="38">Timisoara</option>
            <option value="39">Tulcea</option>
            <option value="40">Vaslui</option>
            <option value="41">Zalau</option>
        </select>
          <div class="custom-select">
            <select>
              <option value="0">Specifica locatia:</option>
              <option value="1">Bucuresti</option>
              <option value="2">Alba Iulia</option>
              <option value="3">Alexandria</option>
              <option value="4">Arad</option>
              <option value="5">Bacau</option>
              <option value="6">Baia Mare</option>
              <option value="7">Bistrita</option>
              <option value="8">Botosani</option>
              <option value="9">Braila</option>
              <option value="10">Brasov</option>
              <option value="11">Buzau</option>
              <option value="12">Calarasi</option>
              <option value="13">Cluj-Napoca</option>
              <option value="14">Craiova</option>
              <option value="15">Deva</option>
              <option value="16">Drobeta Turnu-Severin</option>
              <option value="17">Focsani</option>
              <option value="18">Galati</option>
              <option value="19">Giurgiu</option>
              <option value="20">Iasi</option>
              <option value="21">Miercurea Ciuc</option>
              <option value="22">Oradea</option>
              <option value="23">Piatra Neamt</option>
              <option value="24">Pitesti</option>
              <option value="25">Ploiesti</option>
              <option value="26">Ramnicu Valcea</option>
              <option value="27">Resita</option>
              <option value="28">Satu Mare</option>
              <option value="29">Sf. Gheorghe</option>
              <option value="30">Sibiu</option>
              <option value="31">Slatina</option>
              <option value="32">Slobozia</option>
              <option value="33">Suceava</option>
              <option value="34">Targoviste</option>
              <option value="35">Targu Jiu</option>
              <option value="36">Targu Mures</option>
              <option value="37">Focsani</option>
              <option value="38">Timisoara</option>
              <option value="39">Tulcea</option>
              <option value="40">Vaslui</option>
              <option value="41">Zalau</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="Apartamente" class="tabcontent">
          <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="topright">&times</span>
          <h3>Paris</h3>
          <p> oferta speciala: 02 iulie Hotelul x 220 euro </p>
        </div>
        <div id="Vile" class="tabcontent">
          <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="topright">&times</span>
          <h3>Bucharest</h3>
          <p>Bucharest is the capital of Romania.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="Birouri" class="tabcontent">
          <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="topright">&times</span>
          <h3>Berlin</h3>
          <p> Berlin, capitala germană, este renumit pentru o varietate excepțională de atracții, pentru o scenă culturală înfloritoare și pentru un mod de viață atât de rapid și relaxat. Contrastele dintre clădirile istorice și arhitectura contemporană, între tradițional și modern, sunt ceea ce deosebesc acest oraș față de multe altele. Atracțiile Berlinului - de la Poarta Brandenburg până la Cancelaria Federală - spun povestea unei întregi națiuni. Capitala Germaniei găzduiește toate clădirile importante ale guvernului, mai ales Reichstagul istoric, sediul parlamentului german. </p>
        </div>
        <div id="SpatiiComerciale" class="tabcontent">
          <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="topright">&times</span>
          <h3>Roma</h3>
          <p>Rome is the capital of Italy.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="Terenuri" class="tabcontent">
          <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="topright">&times</span>
          <h3>Roma</h3>
          <p>Rome is the capital of Italy.</p>
        </div> -->
      <!--|***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************|-->
    </div>
    <!--|***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************|-->
    <script src="JS/citytabs.js"></script>
    <script src="JS/search.js"></script>
    <script src="JS/selectScript.js"></script>
    <script src="selectTagHandle.js"></script>
    <!--|***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************|-->
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please include only enough code to show the issue, not all of the HTML (and especially not commented code). See [mcve] for hints on minimizing the code.

Comment: u just solved the pb by adding nowrap to select_row :)))))))))))))))))